# How to move Java runtime console to different terminal window?

Tags: java, terminal, inputstream, outputstream

I executed a Java program from the command line in terminal app A. I want to move the console to terminal app B without having to exit and re-execute the program.

I can think of a few potential ways to solve this, ranging from:

A) In Java implement a new InputStream and OutputStream that somehow can be wired to a new process started in terminal app B.

...to

B) Find a way to put the main Java process in terminal app A in the "background" so that original process can be reopened in a terminal app B.

Ideally, I want to be able to "log in to" and "log out of" my Java process from any terminal on my computer. Has anything like this already been accomplished, and which approach would be best to make it myself? I am open to solutions that involve Java code, shell scripts, or both.

My specs:

- OSX: 10.12.4
- Usually running zsh on iTerm

Answer (score 0):

If I was using Linux, the perfect solution would be [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr), a command line tool that allows you to easily switch terminal windows.

On Mac, the best solution I have found is [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html). It can also be used to switch terminal windows but must be invoked before running java in order to work and seems a lot more complex.